# Do not access a variable through a pointer of an incompatible type?

Tags: c, coverity

I write some code like this:

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t ms;
    uint8_t op;
    uint16_t len;
} DATA_HEAD;
```

```
static int data_rcv(uint8_t *rdt)
{
uint16_t op;
int op_king;
DATA_HEAD *pH;

pH = (DATA_HEAD *)rdt;
op_king= data_check(pH->op);
}
```

```
static int data_check(uint8_t op) {
//some code
}
```

I build and get this warning:

> Accessing an object through a pointer pH whose type DATA_HEAD* is incompatible with the type of the object. Do not access a variable through a pointer of an incompatible type.

How to fix this warning? Thanks very much!

Comment: To clarify: this is a warning you get from Coverity static analyser and not by the compiler, correct?

Answer (score 4):

What you try to archive is called "pointer punning". It generally should be avoided at any cost.

The **safest** method of punning types is use of the `memcpy` function.

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t ms;
    uint8_t op;
    uint16_t len;
} DATA_HEAD;

static int data_rcv(void *rdt)
{
    int op_king;
    DATA_HEAD pH;

    memcpy(&pH, rdt, sizeof(pH));
    op_king= data_check(pH.len);
    return op_king;
}
```

`memcpy` function is well known to most modern optimizing compiler and in most circumstances, it will not be called.

In the example above the compiler will generate a simple load from the memory:

```
data_rcv:
        movzx   edi, WORD PTR [rdi+2]
        xor     eax, eax
        jmp     data_check
```

But if the architecture requires for example aligned access to some  datatypes (like Cortex-M0)

```
data_rcv:
        push    {r4, lr}
        sub     sp, sp, #8
        add     r4, sp, #4
        movs    r1, r0
        movs    r2, #4
        movs    r0, r4
        bl      memcpy
        ldrh    r0, [r4, #2]
        bl      data_check
        add     sp, sp, #8
        pop     {r4, pc}
```

Protecting you from HardFaults if accesses are not properly aligned.

Comment: It work, i try add code like this: 

`memcpy(&pHead, rdata, sizeof(pHead));`
I built and the warning is gone. Tks very much!

Comment: `memcpy(&pH, rdt, sizeof(pH))` assumes that `DATA_HEAD` is laid out without any padding between members, or else that the layout of the bytes matches any such padding.

Comment: @JohnBollinger : the original *type punning* fragment makes the same assumption.

Comment: Yes it does, @wildplasser.  And that is related (indirectly) to why Coverity issues a warning about it.

Answer (score 1):

> How to fix this warning?

Supposing based on the function name and parameter type that all you have to start with is a byte array, and that you are supposing that the first four bytes map to the members of a `DATA_HEAD` (including correct byte order for `op`), the simplest thing to do for your particular example is to pick out the wanted bytes directly:

```
static int data_rcv(uint8_t *rdt) {
    int op_king = data_check(rdt[1]);
}
```

The answer is similar if in reality you actually need to construct a complete `DATA_HEAD` for some other use:

```
static int data_rcv(uint8_t *rdt) {
    DATA_HEAD dh = { .ms = rdt[0], .op = rdt[1] };
    memcpy(&dh.len, rdt + 2, sizeof(dh.len));

    int op_king = data_check(dh.op);

    // ...
}
```

Or if you need a `DATA_HEAD` whose lifetime extends beyond return from `data_rcv()`, then you can dynamically allocate it and set the members in similar manner.

What you *cannot* do (without eliciting the warning you present or a similar one), is reinterpret part of an array of bytes in-place as an object that is neither of character type nor of array-of-character type.

Comment: 1. `DATA_HEAD dh = { .ms = rdt[0], .op = rdt[1] };` what is it for?  2. `memcpy(&op, rdt + 2, sizeof(op));` best way of getting into the troubles. Would not pass any code review

Comment: @0___________, 1: as already expressed in the answer, "if in reality you actually need to construct a complete `DATA_HEAD` for some other use".  2. I've no idea what you find objectionable about the `memcpy`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Your last example writes to `op` twice, first from byte 1 then byte 2 - the memcpy is superfluous. It's a bit confusing because a struct member and a local variable in the original code are both named `op`, though the local one is 16 bits.

Comment: `2` could be replaced with `offsetof(DATA_HEAD, len)`

Comment: Thank you, @0___________.  The OP faked me out with the local `op` variable in their code example, and although I saw that it was not actually used, I did not recognize that it didn't even agree in type with the same-named member of `DATA_HEAD`.  Other mistakes followed, but are now corrected.

Comment: @M.M, no, if the assumption were that the byte stream was laid out the same as a `DATA_HEAD`, then it would be better to just `memcpy()` the whole `DATA_HEAD`.  The reason not to do that is that the layouts might not be the same, and in that case, `offsetof(DATA_HEAD, len)` is not an acceptable substitute for the constant `2`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do here, but I'm guessing the argument to the `data_rcv` function should take in a `DATA_HEAD` object or pointer, not a `uint8_t`. You should almost never be converting between pointers to completely different types like this. Also, there's no need to declare your variables before you use them; you can just do `int op_king = data_check(...)`.

I see you've tagged your question with C++, in which a more idiomatic way for this kind of code is using references. Anyway, hope this helps.

Comment: I've removed the C++11 tag since it was irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Generally there is a rule in C which allows us to inspect any type by using a character pointer (`uint8_t*` can normally be assumed to be one) and then access it byte by byte, to get the raw binary representation.

This cannot be done the other way around - you can't take something like an array of `uint8_t` and convert it to a struct. An `uint8_t*` and `DATA_HEAD*` are not compatible pointer types - though when you add an explicit cast as in your code, C allows the pointer conversion itself. The C language actually allows us to convert between all manner of wildly incompatible pointer types. Though in some hardware, doing so could cause instruction traps - it is implementation-defined behavior what will happen.

By adding the cast you tell the compiler "shut up, I (don't) know what I'm doing!". Which is why the message like the one you quoted can only come from a static analyser, which does more in-depth checks for bug sources.

Now the real problems appear when you de-reference the data:

- Depending on where the `uint8_t*` points at, accessing it by an incompatible larger type could be a misaligned access. Some systems can handle such, some can't. Some systems can handle it but produce slower code.
- Even if the `uint8_t*` pointer happens to point at an aligned address, a struct like the one in your example is very likely to contain padding bytes, to ensure that the struct itself is always aligned. If you copy a raw character array of 100% data into such a struct, you will be writing data into padding bytes and lots of data will end up in the wrong place.
- The C type system does not allow you to re-interpret what `uint8_t*` points at as a `DATA_HEAD` type *unless* the pointer actually happens to be pointing at such a struct allocated elsewhere. If it doesn't, this is a so-called "strict aliasing violation" [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) - an undefined behavior bug where you de-reference pointers in a way which isn't supported by the underlying type system.

For these two reasons, the tool is correct to call out this fishy pointer conversion.

Rule of thumb: *never covert between different pointer types by means of a cast*  unless you actually have in-depth knowledge of C. Otherwise you will likely be creating a lot of subtle but severe bugs.

Possible solutions:

- `memcpy` the data into a struct object, though in that case you have to be aware of potential struct padding.
- Assign the data to a struct object member by member.
- Change the function so that it takes a `DATA_HEAD*` then change the original `uint8_t` buffer into a union, along the lines of: `typedef union { DATA_HEAD dh; uint8_t buf [n]; } foo;`